# using activecell and offset in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to test offset property in excel vba . 
I am using a simple code which selects the cell which is daigonal , i.e 1 row and 1 column away from the active cell.

This is what I am doing

```
Sub Range_Offset()

Range(ActiveCell).Offset(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

I have attached the code to a button on the sheet.

When I am clicking the button , I am getting the following error

```
Run-time error '1004'
Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed
```

If i replacing the ActiveCell with any cell number its working . But why is ActiveCell not working.
Thanks

Comment: Try `ActiveCell.Offset(1,1).Select` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `ActiveCell.Offset(1,1).select`
 `ActiveCell` is already a range object, and you don't need to use `Range()` to turn it into range.